# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-library, aar

I compiled and published an AAR library using Kotlin v1.4.0. When I included this library in another project (which uses Kotlin v1.2.71), it refused to compile and returned this error:

`.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.0/1c752cce0ead8d504ccc88a4fed6471fd83ab0dd/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.4.0, expected version is 1.1.11.`

Questions:

1. Should I have compiled the library with lower Kotlin version?
2. Will apps (without Kotlin dependency) be able to use my library?

Comment: how did you resolve it??

Comment: I am facing the same from hours. Please update solutions if you have found any.